# Matching a url to a route with Regex

Tags: php, regex, url-routing

I have a route like so (YAML):

```
hello_route:
    path: /hello
    controller: HelloController
    action: helloAction
```

this works fine and calls the correct controller and action, but I am having a hard time matching wildcards. For instance, if I wanted to add:

```
hello_route:
   path: /hello/{name}
   controller: HelloController
   action: helloAction
```

I tried using Regex but when you type `/hello/bob` in the browser, no matter what I did with regex it kept saying there was no route. How can I use regex for the URI `/hello/bob` to still match `/hello/{name}`? As of right now it literally looks for the `/{name}` which obviously `!= /bob`

I am using this function so far because I thought that replacing the `{name}` with a `*` would make the browser treat it as a wild card. But that doesn't work.

```
/**
 * Compiles routes
 *
 * @param  array $routes
 * @return string
 */
public function compileRoutes(array $routes)
{
    foreach($routes as $key => $val)
    {
        if($val['path'])
        {
            preg_match_all('/\{(\w+?)}/', $val['path'], $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER);

            foreach ($matches as $match)
            {
                if(isset($matches[0]) && isset($matches[1]))
                {
                    $matches[0] = '*';
                    $val['path'] = $matches[0];
                    $this->params[] = $matches[1]; 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $this->routes = $routes;
}
```

here is the return for @Tuga

```
/
/test
/hello/{name} <- not being replaced
```

Comment: Can you double check the value of  `$route['path']` ?

Comment: @Tuga the output that the above function gives is the same. So the regex is not working. It is not replacing the {name} with *

Comment: What I want to know is if this returns true `if($val['path'])`? if so, please post the output.

Comment: @Tuga it returns true if that is what you mean.

Comment: Can you post an example of path value ?

Comment: @Tuga please look above. There are currently 3 routes the foreach loops through 3 times and if I print `$val['path']` that is what I get

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want, but the syntax of this regex is wrong

```
\{(\w+?)}
```

It needs to be, either this :

```
\{(\w+?)\}
```

or this:

```
(\w+?)
```